# How to generate types from value which is being passed in function as a param?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have function which accepts array of objects here `items` prop takes an array of objets,
then the items get passed again to the Header & Content component.

Is there any way that I can generate the types based on the data which is being passed in the function.

So that I can get prop types for the the Header & Content component.

Here is the code

```js
const data = Array.from({ length: 200 }, () => {
  return {
    id: faker.datatype.uuid(),
    title: faker.hacker.noun(),
    content: faker.hacker.phrase(),
  };
});

const HeaderComp = ({ title, isOpen }: { isOpen: boolean }) => (
  <div className="header">
    {title} <span className={`${isOpen}`}>‚ñæ</span>
  </div>
);

const ContentComp = ({ content }) => <p>{content}</p>;

const App = () => {
  return (
      <Accordion
        items={data}
        HeaderComponent={HeaderComp}
        ContentComponent={ContentComp}
      />
  );
};
```

Generated type should be

```js
{id: string; title: string; content: string;}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you missing something here?,.  `function which accepts array of objects items prop`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make out what you're asking. Do you want to auto-generate a type for the `{id: string; title: string; content: string;}` type you're storing in the array? From static data or dynamic data with varying properties?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes you are absolutely right, `{id: string; title: string; content: string;}`
I want this to be automatically generated from the data which user passes

Answer (score 0):

You can get type of a variable with the [typeof operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) and then [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) or subscript the required fields:

```
type DataType = typeof data;
type DataItem = DataType[number];
type HeaderProps = Pick<DataItem, 'title'>;
type ContentProps = DataItem['content'];
```

Note that the resulting type depends on the TS knowledge about `faker` types. If `faker` is not typed you will get `any` for every field.

Comment: I know i can typeof like that but I want to generate types dynamically from function.

Comment: @Shivam - As [I asked you above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71143900/how-to-generate-types-from-value-which-is-being-passed-in-function-params#comment125760476_71143900), from static data or dynamic data with varying properties?

Comment: I edited my question a bit and yes I have static data with types in an object so...